# Support fat finger tapping/click on mobile web

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, touch

With the correct headers, "click" events will be fired without the 300ms delay.

Though the responsiveness of a mobile web app can suffer when a user taps a button and moves it ever so slightly before releasing. In these situations the "touchmove" events will prevent the "click" from firing.

My use case is in retail environments where the tablet will be in a fixed stand. Fast tapping in these environments are not as accurate.

If you "fat finger" the button on the full screen version on Chrome for Android, the text will not appear.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    msg.classList.remove('hide');
    setTimeout(function () {
        msg.classList.add('hide');
}, 750);
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IWTAnDG7s8kUM22qe4Zv?p=preview
Full screen: http://run.plnkr.co/XCfLQCno6WWOMWjS/

Is there a standard way of handling this?

Comment: don't use click, or use fastclick

Comment: You don't need fastclick on Chrome 32+ for Android (as per README).

Comment: The preview link has expired.

Comment: I've created a demo here (this one doesn't expire) https://output.jsbin.com/sobalu/quiet; from my tests, on Android, the issue is present in the browsers I've tested (Chrome, Firefox); in Safari/iOS, the issue is only present if the tap moves vertically (horizontal swipes over the button trigger "click" normally).